# How to use inner join in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, self-join

I have a table name as tnx_line_transfer. Schema like below

[image]

Now i want to generate output like below

**Output**

[image]

I am trying below query but its not showing proper output. what is the issue on this query

```
SELECT
    main_tbl.operator_id,
    main_tbl.production_line
FROM
    tnx_line_transfer main_tbl
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        operator_id,
        max(date) AS max_date
    FROM
        tnx_line_transfer
    GROUP BY
        operator_id
) temp ON main_tbl.operator_id = temp.operator_id
```

If any other alternative easy solution please let me know.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed to join `date` column with `max_date`.

```
SELECT main_tbl.operator_id,
       main_tbl.production_line
FROM   tnx_line_transfer main_tbl
       INNER JOIN (SELECT operator_id,
                          Max(`date`) AS max_date
                   FROM   tnx_line_transfer
                   GROUP  BY operator_id) temp
               ON main_tbl.operator_id = temp.operator_id
                  AND main_tbl.max_date = temp.`date` --here
```

Another way would be using `Sub-Query`

```
SELECT main_tbl.operator_id,
       main_tbl.production_line
FROM   tnx_line_transfer main_tbl
WHERE  `date` = (SELECT Max(`date`)
               FROM   tnx_line_transfer temp
               WHERE  main_tbl.operator_id = temp.operator_id)
```

`Row_Number` concept comes in handy for above scenario but unfortunately `Mysql` doesnot support `Window function's`